# Datatable second row to first row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

In My Datatable iam getting 2 rows like

```
Name Age City

A    20   c 

B    20   c
```

Now i need like second row shifted to First Row and vice versa

```
Name Age City

B    20   c 

A    20   c
```

How can i do it.

Comment: What if the table has three or four rows?

Comment: It has only 2 rows.I need first row to move to second and second to first..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to swap two rows you can use following approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i += 2)
{
    object[] row1Items = table.Rows[i].ItemArray;        // works because ItemArray creates a new object[]
    table.Rows[i].ItemArray = table.Rows[i+1].ItemArray; // move second to first
    table.Rows[i+1].ItemArray = row1Items;               // move first to second
}
```

It even works with more than two, it swaps every consecutive pair of rows.

Comment: Thanks for Solution Tim.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to sort rows in your DataTable by Name. 
To achieve this, you can use the following example :

```
Dim dv As DataView = dt.DefaultView 
dv.Sort = "Name desc" ' Where "Name" is your column name
dt = dv.ToTable()
```